# How to enter symbols in a tabular environment

Tags: tables, symbols

Is there a simple way of entering symbols within a tabular environment? I'd like to add a degree symbol and a plus/minus symbol to the table below:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering  
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
        \hline
        Property        & Value         \\ \hline
        Chemical symbol & Hg            \\
        Atomic number   & 80            \\
        Density         & 13.534 g cm-3 \\
        Melting point   & -38.8290 \textdegree C   \\
        Atomic mass     & 200.59 \textpm 0.02 u \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{title}
    \label{key}
\end{table}
```

The code above produces an `undefined control sequence` error.

Edit: My problem was that I hadn't loaded the `textcomp` package in my preamble

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table formatted with the lines of package `booktabs` and the numbers and symbols via package `siunitx`. Atomic mass taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury_%28element%29).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  separate-uncertainty,
  multi-part-units = single,
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Properties of mercury}
    \label{tab:Hg}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
      \toprule
        Property        & Value                                    \\
      \midrule
        Chemical symbol & Hg                                       \\
        Atomic number   & \num{80}                                 \\
        Density         & \SI{13.534}{\gram\per\cubic\centi\meter} \\
        Melting point   & \SI{-38.8290}{\degreeCelsius}            \\
        Atomic mass     & \SI{200.592(3)}{\atomicmassunit}         \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

What's your preamble?

Your code works fine for me if I load the *textcomp* package.

You can also write `$^\circ$` instead of `\textdegree` and `$\pm$` instead of `\textpm`. For this you do not need *textcomp*.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp} %remove if you use $^\circ$ and $\pm$ instead
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering  
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
        \hline
        Property        & Value         \\ \hline
        Chemical symbol & Hg            \\
        Atomic number   & 80            \\
        Density         & 13.534 g cm-3 \\
        Melting point   & -38.8290 \textdegree C   \\
%or:    Melting point   & -38.8290 $^\circ$C   \\
        Atomic mass     & 200.59 \textpm 0.02 u \\ \hline
%or:    Atomic mass     & 200.59 $\pm$ 0.02 u \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{title}
    \label{key}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks that solved the problem, I'd clicked on the shortcuts in TexStudio. Is there any difference, aside from convenience, to your different solutions (with and without `textcomp`? Would the version without using `textcomp` be best practice?

Comment: @Bprodz `$^\circ$` is not the real degree sign, compare the output by `$^\circ$` and `\textdegree`. So textcomp would be the best practice. About `\textpm`, take care with the spacing after the command. If you want a space after it, you have to use `\,` to create it.

Comment: the code here will produce a hyphen rather than a minus in the "melting point" line.  minus is only produced in math mode.  the `siunitx` package produces more consistent and proper results with data of this sort.